# In Wildfly 11, how do I suppress the creation of a console.log file?

Tags: logging, jboss, wildfly, console.log, wildfly-11

I'm using Wildfly 11.  I noticed my $WILDFLY_HOME/standalone/log/ directory contains

```
audit.log    console.log  server.log
```

although console.log and server.log seem to contain similar output.  Is there a way to suppress the console.log file from being created?  Below is the (I think) relevant portion of my $WILDFLY_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml file

```
<profile>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:3.0">
        <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
        </console-handler>
        <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
            <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
            <append value="true"/>
        </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
        <logger category="com.arjuna">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="sun.rmi">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <root-logger>
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                <handler name="FILE"/>
            </handlers>
        </root-logger>
        <formatter name="PATTERN">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
        </formatter>
        <formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
        </formatter>
    </subsystem>
```

Answer (score 1):

To disable console log, you have  to comment `<handler name="CONSOLE"/>` in root-logger tag.

Comment: If I remove the section "<console-handler name="CONSOLE">...</console>" my server does not start up at all.

Comment: You have to remove/comment <handler name="CONSOLE"/> from <root-logger> tag as well.

Comment: You can use CLI to remove it as well. `/subsystem=logging/root-logger=ROOT:remove-handler(name="CONSOLE")`.